# On $C^0 [0, 1]$, define $f \cdot g = \int_0^1 f(x) g(x) dx$. For $f(x) = x$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> a. find $||f||$
>
> b. find all linear polynomials that are orthogonal to $x$

Okay, so I know that

$||f|| = \sqrt(f_1^2 + f_2^2 +... + f_n^2)$

and that linear polynomials are of the form $ax + b$

I am not sure however, how to apply these to the actual question..

Comment: $\|f\|=1/\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Thanks, I got that. @user40615

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a scalar product $(f,g)$ then the norm is defined by $\|f\| = \sqrt{(f,f)}$. In your case 
$$ \|f\|^2 = \int_0^1 f(x)^2 dx$$

To find $\|f\|$ you just need to integrate $x^2$ from $0$ to $1$.

If you have a linear polynomial $ax+b$ which is orthogonal to $x$ then their scalar product is zero, so
 $$ \int_0^1 x (ax+b)dx =0$$
and computing the integral you arrive at a necessary and sufficient condition for $a,b$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I understand completely.

Comment: I calculated the integral and got $a/3 + b/2$, just checking that that is the necessary and sufficient condition? @Beni Bogosel

Comment: @zhoe: Remember to upvote and/or mark as accepted answer if this was helpful...